# Не работает $(this)

Tags: jquery

```
  echo '<div class="jumbotron">';
            while ($user = $usr->fetch()) {
                echo "<div><a href='#'" .
                    "data-id='" . $user['id'] . "'>" .
                    htmlspecialchars($user['name']) .
                    "</a></div>";


  $(".jumbotron > div > a").on('click', () => {
                var url = "user.php?id=" + $(this).data('id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: encodeURI(url)
                }).done((data) => {
                    $('#info').html(data).removeClass('hidden');
                });
            });
```

Comment: Консоль что-нибудь пишет? И попробуйте вместо `$(this).data('id')` использовать `$(this).attr('data-id');`

Comment: $(this).attr('data-id') пробовал, не помогло   [200]: GET /user.php?id=undefined

Comment: `...on('click', function() {...`